# Websocket data refresh at certain time interval

Tags: angular, laravel, websocket, ratchet

we are using websocket  between two pages:

```
page1: users who are doing actions
page2: moderator who is moderating user data
```

we want to refresh the page2 moderation data at every 5 seconds using websocket, do you have any any suggestion please?

In short, it should be real time at every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the concept of web sockets, There is no need for the concept of "refreshing" in their usage as the purpose of web socket is to create a live platform that is "reactive" and reacts on the occurrence of an event.

You need to read up on and grasp the concept of broadcasting, listening, events...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting

In broadcasting there is a middle man concept ([Laravel Echo Server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) (self host) or [Pusher.com](https://pusher.com/channels) (Paid Service) that is responsible for creating a service that the users subscribe to and listen for events, the service pushes events out to the subscribed users upon the service receiving an event that was broadcast to it.

A close match for what you are trying to do would be to Search for "*Laravel (Vue/Angualr) chat tutorials*" for understanding the concept of creating a communication between two users like this one:

https://appdividend.com/2018/05/19/laravel-vue-chat-application-tutorial/

A web socket serves as providing a means of maintaining a persistent connection to where events and can be listened for and the connection terminated when the user terminates it by exiting not by timeouts.